# String dereferencing in string literal

Tags: php

Ok, so I am a little curious about the following

```
$string = "Hello world!";

$files = (object)[
    "file" => (object)[
        "name" => "filename.txt",
        "tmp_name" => "tempfile.txt"
    ]
];
```

If I try to echo the following ... `echo "$string";` it does work. But this `echo "$files->file->name";` it does not work. Why is that if both are strings. I understand one is an object and another one is a string but why the string in the object can't be derefrenced. Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing about dereferencing here. It's about php's understanding what you want to print.

Do you want to print `$files` object and string `'->file->name'`?

Or do you want to print `$files->name` property and string `'->name'`?

Or do you want to print value of `name` property or `file` property of `$files` object?

Proper code is

```
echo "{$files->file->name}";
```

Or just:

```
echo $files->file->name;
```

More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

Answer (score 1):

While parsing your string, php does not know what is part of your variable and what isn't (it'll stop at the first `-` as that cannot be part of a variable name...).

You can solve that using `{...}`:

```
<?php
$string = "Hello world!";

$files = (object)[
    "file" => (object)[
        "name" => "filename.txt",
        "tmp_name" => "tempfile.txt"
    ]
];
echo "{$files->file->name}";
```

[An example.](https://eval.in/723214)